# What does the CSP nonce implementation look like?

Tags: reactjs, http-headers, google-tag-manager, content-security-policy, nonce

I've been reading CSP stuffs recently, but I failed to find a clear explanation or solid example about how nonce gonna work. I tried to avoid using `unsafe-inline` for security concerns.

So far, my understanding is like the following:

A server will generate a new nonce every connection
A client gets this nonce by **a certain way** and inserts this string into each script tag

However, I have no idea how the client will get this value which is dynamic and unique among each connection. What is **a certain way** be like? Should I implement an extra API to get this value?

I used React.js and there's a [Google Tag Manager snippet](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web) in my HTML head, if someone can provide the example related to these would be perfect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React applications is a SPA(Single Page Application) so content is loaded using `XMLHttpRequest()` and inserted without page reloading. Therefore `'nonce-value'` is not used since you have no way to generate a new 'nonce' each time page refreshing.

The `'nonce'` can be used when SSR (Server Side Rendering), in this case server can gererate fresh `'nonce'` value and insert it into HTML code been sent (into `<script nonce='value'>`,  `<script src ='some_url' nonce='value'>`, `<style nonce='value'>` and `<link href='some_url' nonce='value' rel='stylesheet'>`).

For this reason, React applications use `'hash-value'` to allow inline scripts and styles.
For example `react-static-plugin-csp-meta-tags` package adds a CSP meta tag to your html files and adding hashes for all inline script and style tags.

Comment: Big thanks. A great answer which really answers my confusion on how to insert dynamic values to a React build. I didn't do SSR on my project, so I'll go with the hash way.

Comment: @grantly, I suddenly found this article, it said CSP is only feasible with the HTML meta tag in React. Don't know why sending headers from the server-side is impossible? Do you have any thoughts on this?
https://csplite.com/csp200/

Comment: Of course, you can send any HTTP headers including CSP when you sent the initial React app.

Comment: @granty Could you please provide a link to this subject and how it is done? That would be great.