# Does the "Sign In with Google" button require CSP style-src 'unsafe-inline'?

Tags: content-security-policy, google-identity

I added a "Sign In with Google" button to my test web app.

I tried to add a CSP following the advise at [Setup instructions > Content Security Policy](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid):

```
script-src https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client;frame-src https://accounts.google.com/gsi/;connect-src https://accounts.google.com/gsi/;style-src https://accounts.google.com/gsi/style;report-uri https://localhost.rubenlaguna.com/csp-report;default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';font-src 'self' https: data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src-attr 'none';upgrade-insecure-requests
```

The button displays ok, but I see a CSP violation for `style-src-elem` reported:

```
csp-report {
  'csp-report': {
    'document-uri': 'https://localhost.rubenlaguna.com/',
    referrer: '',
    'violated-directive': 'style-src-elem',
    'effective-directive': 'style-src-elem',
    'original-policy': "script-src https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client;frame-src https://accounts.google.com/gsi/;connect-src https://accounts.google.com/gsi/;style-src https://accounts.google.com/gsi/style;report-uri https://localhost.rubenlaguna.com/csp-report;default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';font-src 'self' https: data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src-attr 'none';upgrade-insecure-requests",
    disposition: 'enforce',
    'blocked-uri': 'inline',
    'line-number': 383,
    'column-number': 8676,
    'source-file': 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client',
    'status-code': 200,
    'script-sample': ''
  }
}
```

I can get rid of the violation by adding `'unsafe-inline'` to the `style-src`. But I was wondering if it actually required or not, or if there is a way to get rid of this violation by changing the CSP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to avoid the `unsafe-inline` completely by using `nonce` (See [CSP nonce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src), [style-src nonce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/style-src))

The CSP violation happens because the google client library (https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client) creates some inline styles. Fortunately, the client library will "pass-through" the `document.currentScript.nonce` to the inline style. If the inline style has a nonce then you can suppress the CSP violation by allowing `'nonce-xxxx'`

First, you need to pass a `nonce` value to the google client library like this

```
<script nonce="xxx123" src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

the `nonce` should be random value that changes in every reload (see examples below on how to achieve this with express.js)

Then, you add the following in your CSP

```
style-src https://accounts.google.com/gsi/ 'nonce-xxx123';
```

If you are using express.js to generate your pages  you could have a middleware like this to generate the `nonce`, store it in the request and set the `Content-Security-Policy` header:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => { // express middleware
  req.nonce = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("base64url"); // we'll use when rendering the HTML
  const csp = [
    `script-src https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client;`,
    `frame-src https://accounts.google.com/gsi/;`,
    `connect-src https://accounts.google.com/gsi/;`,
    `style-src https://accounts.google.com/gsi/style 'nonce-${req.nonce}';`, // NOTE: allow the nonce
    `report-uri ${process.env.SITE_ADDRESS}/csp-report;`,
    "default-src 'self';",
    "base-uri 'self';",
    "font-src 'self' https: data:;",
    "form-action 'self';",
    "frame-ancestors 'self';",
    "img-src 'self' data:;",
    "object-src 'none';",
    "script-src-attr 'none';",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests",
  ];
  const csp1 = csp.join("");
  res.header("Content-Security-Policy", csp1);
  next();
});
```

Then the `req.nonce` can be used to render the page (using EJS templates):

```
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.render("login", {
    google_client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    site_address: process.env.SITE_ADDRESS,
    nonce: req.nonce, //NOTE: the EJS template needs this value
  });
});
```

that will render the template at `views/index.ejs` using `<script nonce="<%=nonce%>" ...`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <script nonce="<%=nonce%>" src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div>
      <div
        id="g_id_onload"
        data-client_id="<%=google_client_id%>"
        data-context="signin"
        data-ux_mode="redirect"
        data-login_uri="<%=site_address%>/sign-in-with-google-callback"
        data-itp_support="true"
      ></div>

      <div
        class="g_id_signin"
        data-type="standard"
        data-shape="rectangular"
        data-theme="outline"
        data-text="signin_with"
        data-size="large"
        data-logo_alignment="left"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If implementing nonce is difficult in your situation (for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69954946/1763510), you can also use the hash to allow execution of that specific script.  Essentially, just copy and paste the hash from the error in the console, so that your CSP looks like this:

```
style-src https://accounts.google.com/gsi/style 'sha256-owinsowk2n3lk2yHPg9TOCjIt+o5pSFNU/T2oLxDPF+uw=';
```

More info about the hash method can be found here:

https://www.bryanbraun.com/2021/08/10/allowing-inline-scripts-in-your-content-security-policy-using-a-hash/

One major drawback is that this hash value will only work with this exact version of the injected style in google's script.  Any changes made by google, will require the hash value in the CSP to updated. However, I am not sure how often google updates this code.